# Is it possible with 3D textures in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, glsl, textures

Hi I have done Volume Rendering in Kivy for a while now with the 2D texture approach. I want to try with 3D texture as it gives some benifits.
However, I cant see the C OpenGL binding for 3Dtexture buffers in the Kivy API.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293436/how-to-bind-a-texture-to-a-3d-mesh-in-kivy) help ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, they discusse the use of 2D texture on a 3D mesh. Not 3D texture, but thanks!